# Applying equation to column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I have a spreadsheet which has data under an x and y column. There's some y values that are missing and I need to make a script file that uses the x values and computes the missing y values using a linear equation.

Also, there is parts in the y column that has data and then it is missing data and then there's data etc. Is there also a way to use the equation on all the cells in a range except the cells where there is already a y value.

I can provide a sample workbook if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

EDIT:
I've posted a link of what I attempted. I'm a novice at Excel so it might not be the best attempt.

```
Sub LinearCorrelation()
    Dim Data As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer
    Data = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Select
    Result = 2 * Data + 12.5
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D2").Value = Result
End Sub
```

When I run the above script. I get -1 in the D2 which is wrong. The value for 'Data' is 10 so the answer should read 32.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a quite a few issues in your code, so I will try and address them by example.  See inline comments below

```
Sub LinearCorrelation()
    Dim xRange As Range
    Dim yRange As Range
    Dim xData As Variant
    Dim yData As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' for ease of updating later
    Const Slope = 2#
    Const Intercept = 12.5

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")  '<-- lets assume all data is on this sheet
        Set xRange = .Range("A1") '<-- adjust to suit the location of your x data.  Use a single cell at the top of your data.
        Set yRange = .Range("B1") '<-- adjust to suit the location of your y data.  Use a single cell at the top of your data.

        ' expand range to include all x data rows
        Set xRange = .Range(xRange, .Cells(.Rows.Count, xRange.Column).End(xlUp))
        Set yRange = yRange.Resize(xRange.Rows.Count, 1)

        ' move ranges to variant arrays for speed
        xData = xRange.Value2
        yData = yRange.Value2

        For i = 1 To UBound(xData, 1)
            ' only calculate missing y values
            If IsEmpty(yData(i, 1)) Then
                yData(i, 1) = Slope * xData(i, 1) + Intercept
            End If
        Next i

        ' return data to y range
        yRange = yData
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm used to MATLAB so I thought the equation part could work similar. Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it.